# Unexpected scaling of graphics when using Show

Tags: graphics

Here is my code:

```
vslA = RegionPlot[x > 0, {x, 0, 8}, {y, 0, 1},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 1, .4]]
fslA = RegionPlot[x > 0, {x, 8, 14}, {y, 0, 1},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.2, 0.8, .4]]
Show[fslA, vslA, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

But unfortunately, instead of a long rectangle with about 57% area of one color and 43% area of a different color, I am getting this graphic:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? I plan to create a big graphic by specifying coordinates of every little piece and I have worked out the coordinates just so the shapes and positions come out exactly where I want them but already just the first piece has me stumped.

Comment: Show take options from the first argument. Hence `Show[p1,p2]` will use `p1` options for the overall plot. You can override the options inside Show, or if you know which p you want to use for all the options, put that as the first in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Show[fslA, vslA, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
     AspectRatio -> (AspectRatio /. AbsoluteOptions[fslA, AspectRatio])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]